# Recursively iterate over an array without changing its size

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, computer-science

I am currently trying to solve this problem in Java, but I do not want to set myself onto a specific language since I think of this as a "general" problem.

The conditions for the function I am looking for are:

- the only values that can be modified are the values inside the array to be iterated over. Thus, for example, you **can not use other variables** that store any kind of information, such as indices (which by the way also eliminates the possibility of looping through the array). This also applies to function parameters. The **only argument** that is passed to the function is the **array itself**.
- additionally to the previous point: **memory space must be consistent**. Therefore, you **cannot copy** the current array onto a bigger/smaller array.

However:

- the array is an **integer array**
- the function might **return an integer value**
- the elements inside the array might be **changed**, but only after they are iterated over
- the array does **not** have to be iterated in any kind of **order**, but every element has to be "reached" **exactly once**.
- there exists a function that returns the **length** of the array

the signature might look like this (again, no specific language, but since I am currently working in Java, the signature is in Java syntax):

```java
int iterate(int[] integerArray)
```

**Is it possible to write such a function?**

One attempt of mine was to traverse the array from index `0` to `length(array) - 1`, storing the current index at `array[0]`, and exit if `array[0]` (or `array[prev]`) is `length(array) - 1`. So, in order to get the next array element, I would do something like `array[array[0]]` and increment the counter in `array[0]`. The major problem with this is that I have to somehow catch the first function call to `iterate()` in order to initialize `array[0]` with `0`.

Comment: In which language is this? In such cases, I think `static` variable comes handy looking at your function signature.

Comment: is there any operation to split the array in any way? If yes, easy, if not I can't see how to make this.

Comment: Depending on the language you use, you can recursively call the method with the tail of the array, and count the elements by the recursion depth. So my answer is YES it is possible.

Comment: "You cannot use other variable". First comment "static variable"... gets two upvotes. :/

Comment: @MrSmith42 The tail would be a slice, which constitutes "copying onto a shorter array" which is explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: depends on the implementation of tail. It can also simply be a pointer to the second element of the same array (so no copy of any data).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a variable but a parameter (the only thing we can work with, otherwise I don't see how it could work), here an example to find max:

```js
function findMax(arr, index = 0, max = Number.MIN_VALUE) {
  if (index < arr.length)
    return findMax(arr, index + 1, arr[index] > max ? arr[index] : max)
  return max
}

console.log(findMax([7,9,2,8,6]))
```

Or another example with modification, reverse array (without variable for the swap, alternatively you could just write a helper function to do the swapping):

```js
function reverseArray(arr, index = 0, value = arr[0]) {
  if (index < arr.length) {
    reverseArray(arr, index + 1, arr[index + 1]) // iterate over the whole array
    // any modification here will happen after the whole array was iterated
    if (index < arr.length / 2) {
      arr[index] = arr[arr.length - index - 1]
      arr[arr.length - index - 1] = value
    }
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(reverseArray([7,9,2,8,6]))
```

If you are using a language where you cannot specify predefined values, then you can just overload the method or create a helper, e.g. java:

```
public int findMax(int[] arr) {
    findMax(arr, 0, arr[0]);
}

private int findMax(int[] arr, int i, int max) {
    if (i < arr.length)
        return findMax(arr, i + 1, arr[i] > max ? arr[i] : max);
    return max;
}
```